# Efficiently find matches between two tables with multiple values

Tags: sql, join, db2

I am looking for the most efficient way to return records from one table which have a matching number in another table.

What I am trying to do is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS
WHERE MODEL IN (SELECT MODEL FROM CAR_MAKES 
                WHERE YEAR = 2018)
```

So basically, I have a year, and I want to get all models from the CAR_MAKES table for 2018 (n number) and I want to return everything from the CARS table for each model returned (n number).

I only want to return the contents of the CARS table, nothing else.

I know that there are a few ways of looking at this. From what I can see, the 'WHERE IN' statement is not efficient so it would be better to go down the route of using joins.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks.

UPDATE:

This is what I have got now:

```
SELECT C.* FROM CARS AS C
JOIN CAR_MAKES CM ON
C.MODEL = CM.MODEL
WHERE CM.YEAR = 2018
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products do different optimizations.)

Comment: This is on IBM DB2.

Comment: Try  LEFT Join and select all from the LEFT table

Comment: 1) You cannot _guess_ the efficiency of a query; you must compare alternatives' query plans and measure actual performance for an objective answer. 2) Your left join is useless in the presense of `WHERE CM.YEAR = 2018`

Comment: I' have removed the 'LEFT' in the join. Having done some brief comparisons between the different queries I wrote, I can see that the join is the quickest by a small margin. A much larger dataset will tell all though.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` would show you `Cars` that do not have an entry in  `Car_Makes`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM CARS C
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CAR_MAKES CM ON C.id = CM.carsId
 WHERE CM.YEAR = 2018
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN and right side table condition in WHERE clause... How come?

Comment: It is good practice to provide some explanation to your answer.